# Print error message after validation fails

Tags: yii

Im new to Yii. I have a form where users can publish an article. I want to make sure users can only publish an article if the publish date of the previous article is more than an hour ago.

So in the model I have:

```
    protected function beforeSave()
    {
        //get the last time article created. if more than an hour -> send        
        $lastArticle = Article::model()->find(array('order' => 'time_created DESC', 'limit' => '1'));

        if($lastArticle){
            if(!$this->checkIfHoursPassed($lastArticle->time_created)){
                return false;
            }
        }

        if(parent::beforeSave())
        {
            $this->time_created=time();
            $this->user_id=Yii::app()->user->id;

            return true;
        }
        else
            return false;
    }
```

This works, but how do I display an error message on the form? If i try to set error with:

```
$this->errors = "Must be more than an hour since last published article";
```

I get a "read only" error....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you are describing a validation rule, you should be putting this code in a custom validation rule instead of in `beforeSave`. This will take care of the problem:

```
public function rules()
{
    return array(
       // your other rules here...
       array('time_created', 'notTooCloseToLastArticle'),
    );
}

public function notTooCloseToLastArticle($attribute)
{
    $lastArticle = $this->find(
        array('order' => $attribute.' DESC', 'limit' => '1'));

    if($lastArticle && !$this->checkIfHoursPassed($lastArticle->$attribute)) {
        $this->addError($attribute, 
                       'Must be more than an hour since last published article');
    }     
}
```